# Is there a way to make F# keep the type of a parameter generic?

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# (and enjoying it so far), and I've been experimenting with code. I found something that I understand the cause of but not how to overcome it.

I have some code similar to the following:

```
let pairTest list = if List.length list = 2 then Some list else None

// This seems to compile and work just fine
[ [1; 2] ]
|> List.choose pairTest
|> List.map (fun l -> l |> List.map (fun i -> "a"))
|> List.choose pairTest
|> printfn "%A"

let testFunc groupTest =
  [ [1; 2] ]
  |> List.choose groupTest // Okay
  |> List.map (fun l -> l |> List.map (fun i -> "a"))
  |> List.choose groupTest // Error: expected int list, not string list
  |> printfn "%A"

testFunc pairTest
```

I understand how F#'s type inference works, and I can see that in testFunc it's hitting `int list` on the first call to `groupTest` and then assigning that type (and examining the `groupTest` paramter in an IDE shows the type as `int list -> int list option`), which then makes it invalid for its second invocation. However, if I run the code outside of a function (the first function block), it works just fine and seamlessly switches `pairTest<'a>` between `int list` and `string list`.

My question is this: Is there a way to keep F# from locking down the type of `groupTest`? Or, if not, is there an (F#-idiomatic) way to approach this?

In this specific instance, I can just pass in a `length` parameter and move the `List.length` check inside the function, but I'm still curious about the answer for the more general case (if, say, my check were more complex, for instance.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done in F# with just ordinary functions. The issue is that in F#, you cannot pass a generic function as an argument to another function. When F# prints the type of your `testFunc`, you get:

```
('a list -> 'a list option) -> unit
```

The key thing here is that `'a` is a type variable that is fixed when you invoke the function. Formally, there is a universal quantification over the whole type, i.e.:

```
forall 'a . (('a list -> 'a list option) -> unit)
```

This means that when you call `testFunc`, you first set `'a` to one specific type. What you need here (and what F# does not support) is to have the quantification only for the type of the argument:

```
(forall 'a . ('a list -> 'a list option)) -> unit
```

If you could do this, then the body of the function could, itself, be able to set `'a` to two different types when it accesses the function. This cannot be done in F# with plain functions, but you can encode this using an interface:

```
type GroupTest =
  abstract Invoke<'T> : 'T list -> 'T list option
```

This interface has a generic method, i.e. essentially a function of type `(forall 'a . ('a list -> 'a list option))`. You can then write `testFunc` as a function of `GroupTest -> unit`:

```ml
let testFunc (groupTest:GroupTest) =
  [ [1; 2] ]
  |> List.choose groupTest.Invoke
  |> List.map (fun l -> l |> List.map (fun i -> "a"))
  |> List.choose groupTest.Invoke
  |> printfn "%A"

testFunc { new GroupTest with member x.Invoke a = pairTest a }
```

The syntax for this is a bit clumsy, so I would only use this trick if it was something essential about my domain. If you need this just in one place, you're probably better off with a simple trick like duplicating the argument (or maybe duplicating the whole `testFunc` function for each different `groupTest`). But the interface trick works and it's a general way to do what you're asking about.

```ml
let testFunc groupTest1 groupTest2 =
  [ [1; 2] ]
  |> List.choose groupTest1
  |> List.map (fun l -> l |> List.map (fun i -> "a"))
  |> List.choose groupTest2
  |> printfn "%A"

testFunc pairTest pairTest
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted to know. I especially appreciate the formalism in your reply.